# When powering down kali linux, I get the message "Other users are logged in."

Tags: linux, kali-linux, liveusb

This is what is displayed:

[image of what is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqb5u.jpg)

I am currently logged in as root, so is root (console) a separate user? I just finished setting everything up so I can boot kali from a usb with persistence, and I am not sure if this is a sign that I made a mistake that could come back to bite me. Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm new to this stuff, but thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: Did you ever find your answer? If so, could you share?